# MongoDB $pull syntax

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having a (hopefully) small syntax problem with `$pull` in Mongodb.

```
bulk.find({_id: new mongo.ObjectID(req.session._id)}).updateOne({$pull: {
  firstArray: {id: req.params.id},
  'secondArray.firstArrayIds': req.params.id
  'secondArray.$.firstArrayIds': req.params.id
}});
```

The firstArray `$pull` works just fine.
But the secondArray.firstArrayIds and/or `secondArray.$.firstArrayIds` does not. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my data structure:

```
clients: {
  firstArray: [
    {
      _id: '153'.
      someField1: 'someVal1',
    }
    ...
  ]

  secondArray: [
    {
      _id: '7423'.
      someField1: 'someVal1',
      firstArrayIds: [153, 154, 155, ...]
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

**EDIT** What if there are more than one embedded object in `secondArray` which `firstArrayIds` can contain the id i want to delete. In other words, when deleting an object in `firstdArray` i want to delete references in **all** `secondArray`'s `firstArrayIds` Not just the first match.

Comment: You need to identify the `secondArray` element to update in your query object so that `$` will work.  Also, I assume that `firstArrayIds` doesn't contain a single string like you show?

Comment: You assume right! Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "secondArray" has a nested element structure, so you must identify the outer element you want to match in your query when using a positional `$` operator in the update. You basically need something like this:

```js
bulk.find({ 
    "_id": new mongo.ObjectID(req.session._id), 
    "secondArray._id": "7423" 
}).update({
    "$pull": { 
        "firstArray": { "_id": "153" },
        "secondArray.$.firstArrayIds": 153
    }
});
```

So there are in fact "two" id values you need to pass in with your request in addition to the general document id. Even though this is nested it is okay since you are only matching on the "outer" level and only on one array. If you tried to match the position on more than one array then this is not possible with the positional operator.

Comment: I edited my question regarding the topic I know you have been touching in your answers. I have been searching for ways to affect more than one array, and it seems that this is not possible right now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765077/pull-multiple-object-in-mongo-does-not-work Or is there a way?

Comment: @AndersÖstman Depends on what you mean by more than one array. As I pointed to and also mentioned in that link, is that you cannot "match the position" in more than one array or in anything other than a "top level" array. But you can always use the "same" matched  position, which is often a cheat. If you have a specific case then you can always post another question. Probably best formed as looking for a solution to what you are trying to achieve. This form of update works, and a general workaround for "more than one" is multiple operations in bulk. But another question makes the case clear.

Comment: A new question is up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179021/pull-object-from-array-and-pull-references-in-another-array

Comment: @AndersÖstman before I comment there, that looks like very much the same question and therefore has the same answer. Is there some reason that you think the above does not work?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how to express myself in another way. When you reference "the above" in your previous comment. Do you mean your answer, or do you mean comment starting with: "Depends on...", that maybe gives me an answer i dont understand. =P

Comment: @AndersÖstman Doesn't matter. Your new question explains itself well enough on a further reading.