# How to delete the field in the mongodb collection?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database, mongodb

I have a data collection in mongodb like below:

```
{
    { "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "name" : "ABC", "group" : [ObjectId("11"), ObjectId("12"), ObjectId("13")]}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "name" : "DEF", "group" : [ObjectId("21"), ObjectId("22"), ObjectId("23")]}
}
```

I want to delete `ObjectId("11")` in the `group` field in document
 `ObjectId("1")`.

I tried the code below:

```
aId = "1" 
bId = "11"
db.collection.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(aId) }, { $pull: { group: { _id: ObjectId(bId) } } })
```

But failed.

I have also tried:

```
aId = "1" 
bId = "11"
db.collection.updateOne({ _id: aId }, { $pull: { group: { _id: bId } } })
```

But still failed to delete it.

Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: The field group is just an array of Object Ids . Try `db.collection.updateOne({ _id: aId }, { $pull: { group: bId } })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB $pull syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165650/mongodb-pull-syntax)

Comment: @MukulDev agreed. But it needs to be `ObjectId(bId)`, does it not?

Comment: @Coolguy Yes it should be  `objectId(bId)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$unset` like this:

```
db.products.update(
{ sku: "unknown" },
{ $unset: { quantity: "", instock: "" } })
```

This code will remove the fields quantity and instock from the firstdocument in the products collection where the field sku has a value of unknown.
[For more info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)